# Can't understand 3-way switch diagram for smart switch

Tags: switches

I'm replacing a traditional light switch for a smart one (S1). This switch is connected in a 3-way with another traditional switch (S2) which won't be replaced. So in the end it's one smart and one traditional switch in a conventional 3-way connection.

The wiring instructions include the following diagram:
[image]

I understand most of it except this: **if S1 is powering the red/black wire how can S2 turn the light off?** Is that because the electricity would go through the jumper and then through the blue/red wire back to S1, kind of a "shortest path"? If so, would that consume electricity when the light is off?

Thank you for your inputs.

PS: please pardon my terminology, I'm not familiar with the subject.

Comment: We don't know which smart switch that is and how it works internally. It might have some detection circuitry to monitor the state of remote switch if it is close or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S2 doesn’t power the light.

The blue wire provides a signal to the smart switch (S1) telling it to switch on/off the light when S2 changes position.

This approach uses existing wiring if converting from a conventional three-way switching and minimizes the hardware in the smart switch by only requiring a single device to control the load current.

Comment: When S1 detects the switch on S2 and turns the light off, does that mean that both red and blue wires won't have electricity at the same time?

Comment: both will have electricity, just not enough electricity to light the lamp.